# Should I use static fields in Function class

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have some thoughts, but I can't confirm them.
Let's say that we have need of `HttpClient` class. Creation of it on each call will be fair. Also, it's recommended to [have just single instance of HttpClient](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/69954).
I thought to create the static property for HttpClient and initialize it in the static constructor. Since initialization is thread-safe and HttpClient itself is thread-safe we can safely use it.

Creating static fields save time execution and memory usage of Function. But is it singleton in this case? As I understand AF [can scale out instantly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale). This means that when Azure decides to scale your application it will create new container/VM and balance load between instances. So, in this case, HttpClient field will be the singleton in the scope of container/VM, but not among the apps.

My thoughts are:

1. Use static field/property when you need to reuse it between function call
2. Initialization should be thread safe and object itself too.
3. If there is need of re-initializing of an object, should be used lock.
4. Static property is singleton among current machine(container/vm)

Even if field is not singleton among all instances of AF we still benefit. So are my thoughts right or there is side effects of using them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your conclusions are correct. Caching things like `HttpClient` is highly recommended, not just for memory concerns, but also because it helps keep the number of connections low (you can easily reach the connection limit in the sandbox that functions run in).

Indeed, each instance of the runtime will have its own copy, but it is still very much beneficial because a given instance of the runtime can be used for many executions (in some cases concurrent, hence the need for thread safety).